# Extrema and sign of derivative

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I know, and it is proved,as far as I know, in most standard calculus texts, that, if $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable in $x_0\in(a,b)$ and $f'(x_0)=0$, then

- if $\forall x\in(a,x_0)\quad f'(x)<0$ and $\forall x\in(x_0,b)\quad f'(x)>0$ then $x_0$ is a strict local minimum of $f$;
- if $\forall x\in(a,x_0)\quad f'(x)>0$ and $\forall x\in(x_0,b)\quad f'(x)<0$ then $x_0$ is a strict local maximum of $f$;

and analogously

- if $\forall x\in(a,x_0)\quad f'(x)\le0$ and $\forall x\in(x_0,b)\quad f'(x)\ge0$ then $x_0$ is a local minimum of $f$;
- if $\forall x\in(a,x_0)\quad f'(x)\ge0$ and $\forall x\in(x_0,b)\quad f'(x)\le0$ then $x_0$ is a local maximum of $f$.

I wonder whether the converse implications are true, i.e. whether a (strict or respectively non-strict) minimum implies the existence of intervals $(x_0-\delta,x_0)$ where $f'$ is negative (respectively non-positive) and $(x_0,x_0 +\delta)$ where $f'$ is positive (respectively non-negative), but I have not been able to find a proof, either on books, on line or by myself. Therefore I am beginning to suspect that such converse implications are not true. Can anybody explain why they are true if they are or say that they are not? I $\infty$-ly thank you!

Comment: Typo: the inequalities should involve $f'$ and not $f$.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre Of course... Thank you for noticing, Julián!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider

$$
f(x)=\cases{x^4\Bigl(2+\sin{1\over x}\Bigr), &$x \ne 0$\cr 0, &$x=0$}
$$

This function has a global minimum at $x=0$ but the derivate takes negative and positive values in every open interval with $0$ as an endpoint.

(From: [Counterexamples in Analysis](http://books.google.de/books?id=cDAMh5n4lkkC&pg=PA36&source=gbs_toc_r&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) )

Comment: Another thing to consider would be minima at which the derivative fails to exist.

Comment: Very interesting counterexample and very, very interesting reference! Thank you so much!